# Extract email address from a file before mapping in Talend

Tags: file, talend, file-watcher, automatic-storage

I have a folder with 5 files. One of the files has an email address. I want to extract the email address from the file first, map it to a database, and then store it somewhere as a variable so that it can be used for sending email component using talend. I also want to move the 5 files into another folder. Any idea how can I do that with talend. 
Below is what I did so far using a file watcher. 
(This whole thing should happen automatically, as in, when a new file is added this whole thing should happen)

[image]

Comment: Do you get multiple email addresses or just one email address?

Comment: one at a go, but its automatic (through twaitforfile) therefore each time a new file is added to my directory new email needs to be extracted